# EJS syntax disorders when page saved (Ctrl + S) in VS Code

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, syntax, ejs, script-tag

When I save the page the EJS syntax disorders and data are not going throw to other scripts where I need them.

```
<script>
        const user = <%- JSON.stringify(user) %>
    </script>
```

Adds one space in between the less-than sign and hyphen.

```
<script>
        const user = <% - JSON.stringify(user) %>
    </script>
```

It is working fine when there is no space, but it just annoys me to scroll throw code and delete space every single time I want to save. I have auto-save turned on, but still, I want to use "Ctrl + S", to format data properly.
Did anyone encounter this situation, any suggestions?
I disabled HTML Validate Script in VS Code Settings because it wouldn't be happy for putting EJS syntax into a script tag, and I enabled HTML formatter, so EJS is formating properly when "Ctrl + S" hits.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have a keyboard shortcut to reformat, you'll find it (and change it if you want) at:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>s</kbd>

In any case, you could try using autosave(File/Auto Save)